# Add jQuery active class to menu on a specific url page load

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a nav menu that opens (and closes) on-click.

I want the menu to be always open (without having to click) when a specific page loads.

It's currently set up as:

```
$('.menu').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
  $('nav').toggleClass('active');
});
```

I'm not sure how to get it to stay active on a specific page load.

I've tried this but can't get it to work.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("get-started")
$('.menu').toggleClass('active');
  $('nav').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("get-started") {
  $('nav').addClass('active');
}
```

Add this code directly in document.ready.

Comment: It almost worked. I have to edit slightly to this: ```if(window.location.href.indexOf("get-started") != -1) {
  $('nav').addClass('active');
}```